# Do people still read blogs?

Tags: blog

I am under the impression they do but I have colleagues who believe nobody reads blogs anymore, and that if you must blog, video blogs are better. Any thoughts on this? Is writing becoming redundant?

Comment: Blogs are still being written and read; the question is in what numbers. What kind of information are you looking for? Total number of readers? Influence and reach? Viability of any one blog successfully finding a following?

Comment: Even a video blog needs the process of writing in the format of "script writing" (unless you're talking about spontaneous videos). The process of recording thoughts still requires (and most probably for a long time will require) the concept of writing. How would someone find the aforementioned video and learn its contents beforehand if it isn't recorded in the form of scripture?

Comment: @Montag451: Hayley isn't asking whether writing is required for video blogs; she's asking whether written-word blogs are becoming redundant.

Comment: No answer to this question could ever be reliable if it doesn't bring citations and figures. There are a lot of studies and articles discussing this, so an internet search could provide a better overview than any "people still read my blog so yes" answers could provide.

Answer (score 13):

My blog is still being read, and at about the same level it always was.

But as blogs have become a popular form of content marketing, it is inevitable that fewer and fewer of them are being read. Ineffective marketers pump out boat loads of drivel which people do not read. Since producing something that is not drivel is hard work, they are always chasing the next media fad in hopes that it will get people reading their drivel. They see stats that show fewer blogs are being read and immediately jump to producing videos. Perhaps briefly people who have started to avoid blogs because of the drivel may turn to videos, but as all the drivel producer flock to video, people will see through that as well.

Text and video are both valuable means of expression, each with their own areas of particular strength. But drivel is still drivel and people will not watch drivel just because it a video rather than text. People will consume quality content in whatever media they find it in.

Create quality. Make sure you have something real to say and that you understand who you are saying it to. Choose the media that best suits the message. People will come.

Comment: You answered as I was trying to refine my question and I'm glad to hear your views. The company I work for has a blogging platform, which the marketing team uses extensively. Recently they started simply calling YouTube videos into their blogs, with a short introductory sentence to explain what it's about. With both formats, users don't seem to be engaging - no comments, no subscriptions, not that many views. Sometimes the content is actually quite interesting, but perhaps it's not consistently interesting, so people have lost interest and don't bother anymore.

Comment: If people want YouTube videos, they go to YouTube. If they search Google for videos, it points them to those videos on YouTube, not those embedded in other people's blogs. To get traffic to your site, you have to either post content that ranks well in search engines (quality is the best form of SEO) or build an audience that is willing to visit your site directly or subscribe to your feeds. For that you need consistent quality, not just the occasional good piece.

Answer (score 2):

As the Web continues to develop, I see a trend that can't be denied. Shorter and simpler is far better than lengthy and content focused. Also, comedy seems to be a hit. If you can make it short and make it funny, it becomes memorable and "watch-worthy," if that's a word. If you're blogging about insurance and you drone on and on about shop talk insurance jargon, you just lost at least 70% of those that even gave your blog a fighting chance. If, however, you make it concise, funny and endearing (focusing on common issues your target audience encounters and making light of them), all the while offering a solution, you have the makings of a successful blog/vlog.

Answer (score 0):

I read several blogs each week. If they are relevant, well-written and interesting I take the time to read them. If they aren't, I delete the without reading them.